# Growing tree/fractal type animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, fractals

this is a more "what technology to learn/use" question. Basically I'm a web designer/developer currently in my 2nd year at University and wanting to start developing my owe personalized portfolio website.

I've recently been getting into CSS3 animation and god is that stuff awesome. Anyway my new portfolio idea is to create a website that is essentially animation based. I know CSS animation is currently a limited option and thus want to know if I need to dig my head into some JavaScript to get the desired result. Essentially the website will be like a "garden" or just nature. I to use vector based graphics and have trees grow out of the "ground" upon load, clouds sweep across and other such things.

The most complicated thing I will be animating will be the tree as the clouds and such can be transformed and animated using CSS. Here's an example of how I want the tree to grow and to look like Pythagoras tree.

http://andrew-hoyer.com/experiments/fractals/

I won't be wanting or needing it to grow based on mouse movement or bend to the right or left. Just go from box to pythagoras tree.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use three or d3 or a similar geometry library.

Comment: See also this [d3 tree example](http://prcweb.co.uk/lab/d3-tree/) ([here is the JS sourcecode](http://prcweb.co.uk/lab/d3-tree/js/main.js))

Comment: @IljiaDimov:What about the Example from the comment? Maybe he can try L-systems?!

Comment: As it stands, this answer looks more like a comment. While the comment below it helps (by adding just a link, which can rot), the answer may benefit from expanding upon the idea of using D3 or another geometry library.

Comment: @KevinBrown:D3 is really a big framework. Not sure what you can give more?